# Excel Using COUNTIFS to Conditionally Format Cells with matching strings

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to search a column G to find and highlight matching strings throughout the column. I already used a formula of COUNTIFS to get a total count of the number of times these strings appear within the entire column. However when I copy it to **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** it highlights the entire column instead of the matching cells. Below is an example of the formula.

```
=COUNTIFS($G:$G,"*text1*", $G:$G, "*text2*", $G:$G, "*text3*")
```

returns a total of 42. Presumably 42 cells out of 1600 match that formula. Where all 3 strings are present within the cell. I want to highlight those cells to easily identify them and confirm the remainder of the string.

Comment: Change the `$G:$G` to `G1`, or the first cell in column G containing these strings.

Comment: Well that was easy. I don't understand why that works but it does.

Comment: It works because when using a custom formula for conditional formatting, the formula has to be written how it would apply to the top-left cell of the range that the conditional format will check. Hence if your conditional is to apply to the column G:G, the formula should be written for cell G1.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I'll use that method going forward.